# string.find indexing in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to understand ***why*** the following python code incorrectly returns the string "dining":

```
def remove(somestring, sub):
"""Return somestring with sub removed."""
    location = somestring.find(sub)
    length = len(sub)
    part_before = somestring[:location]
    part_after = somestring[location + length:]
    return part_before + part_after

print remove('ding', 'do')
```

I realize the way to make the code run correctly is to add an if statement so that if the location variable returns a -1 it will simply return the original string (in this case "ding"). The code, for example, should be:

```
def remove(somestring, sub):
"""Return somestring with sub removed."""
    location = somestring.find(sub)
    if location == -1:
        return somestring
    length = len(sub)
    part_before = somestring[:location]
    part_after = somestring[location + length:]
    return part_before + part_after
print remove('ding', 'do')
```

Without using the if statement to fix the function, the part_before variable will return the string "din". I would love to know why this happens. Reading the python documentation on string.find (which is ultimately how part_before is formulated) I see that the location variable would become a -1 because "do" is NOT found. But if the part_before variable holds all letters before the -1 index, shouldn't it be blank and not "din"? What am I missing here?

For reference, Python documentation for string.find states:

`string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])`

Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Comment: `'ding'[-1] == 'g'`. [Negative numbers index backwards from the end](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). This also works for slices, hence `'ding'[:-1]` is everything but the last character. The `if location < 0:` is mandatory, here.

Comment: you need to format your code.  Everything in the function should be indented 4 spaces from the beginning of the def line.

Comment: As a side note, your function does the same as `somestring.replace(sub, '')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = 'ding'
string[:-1]
>>> 'din'
```

Using a negative number as an index in python returns the *n*th element from the right-hand side. Accordingly, a slice with `:-1` return all but the last element of the string.

Comment: Note that you can force  the slice's parameter to `None` to get the last character (`end = None; string[begin:end]`).

Comment: @Cilyan, that's a much appreciated note and preempted my next question. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string `'ding'` and you are searching for `'do'`, `str.find()` will return -1.  `'ding'[:-1]` is equal to `'din'` and `'ding'[-1 + len(sub):]` equals `'ding'[1:]` which is equal to `'ing'`.  Putting the two together results in 'dining'.  To get the right answer, try something like this:

```
def remove(string, sub):
    index = string.find(sub)
    if index == -1:
        return string
    else:
        return string[:index] + string[index + len(sub):]
```

The reason that `string[:-1]` is not equal to the whole string is that in slicing, the first number (in this case blank so equal to `None`, or for our purposes equivalent to 0) is inclusive, but the second number (-1) is exclusive.  `string[-1]` is the last character, so that character is not included.

Comment: If left blank, it is not equal to 0 but to None. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice Try it, you will see the difference.